# rabbitmq unacked messages after channel is dead

Tags: java, rabbitmq, message-queue, amqp, ttl

We have implemented RMQ in our application and it handles around 7 million messages a day. We have set TTL for every queue and also on message level. one queue may have one or multiple consumers.

Now for some unknown reason we are observing few unacked messages getting accumulated in some queues, its not happening always. And the messages are staying  unacked, **even after the channel and/or the consumer is dead**, long after the TTL is over(I guess TTL doesnt matter, when channel is dead anyway).

Any idea will be really helpful.
Thanks !

Comment: I had an issue like this some time ago and it turned out that I was using an outdated version of RabbitMQ. Could you check your RabbitMQ version?

Comment: It is 3.6.6 , which is not too old, and I need to be sure, before making any changes in production, problem is this doesn't happen always..

Comment: I guess 3.6.6 is more than one y.o. which is quite old for minor updates. It's important to fix CVEs and bugs in production, even if it doesn't fix your issue. I highly recommend you upgrade. That being said, I had very similar issues under 3.6.6 with roughly the same throughput. Upgrade to 3.6.12 did fix the issue. Beware though, version 3.6.7 requires a cluster-wide restart, which I did with zero-downtime thanks to the Shovel plugin. However, it's still possible it's a bug in your app (that wouldn't ack msgs for some reason) in which case some reproducible example would be required to help.